# Is it possible to connect external wired camera to ios device?

Tags: ios, camera, usb, uvc

Is it possible to connect external wired USB Webcam to ios device lighting connector? I want to connect USB Webcam to IOS Device.

It maybe possible because there is an [example](http://www.wired.com/2014/10/seek-thermal-infrared-camera-iphone-android/).

But, I don't know It is truely possible.
It must be only wired connection, not wifi beacuse battery problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I wan't develop ios app for using usb camera.

Comment: 99.97% (FMA): If others have done it, yes. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. There are a few ways to do it:
1) Using a jailbreak iPhone with IOKIT to support control and receiving streaming video from the webcam.
2) Develop a MFI complied lightning cable to connect

david